# if constexpr(condition) as compile-time conditional

Tags: c++, c++17, if-constexpr

I want to use a constexpr bool (`useF` in the example below) to enable a feature in the following code. Here, calling `A::f()`. Additionally, I want to be the alias-template (`a`) to be `void` in the case I switch off the feature.

I tried to use a constexpr if statement, but the body is still being instantiated, which causes a compile error. If I use a wrapper template (`X`), the body is being discarded as I'd expected, but that seems ugly to me. Are there any other ways to do this?

```
constexpr bool useF = false;

struct A {
    static void f() {}
};

using a = std::conditional<useF, A, void>::type;

template<typename L>
struct X {
    static void h() {
        if constexpr(std::is_same<L, A>::value) {
            L::f(); // not instantiated, no error
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    if constexpr(useF) {
        a::f(); // error!?
    }

    X<a>::h();
}
```

I am using g++-7.0.1 with -std=c++17

Comment: Sorry, was wrong tags selection! If I select the tag c++17, a tag c++1z is inserted ... strange.

Comment: Because it's [synonym](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b1z/synonyms).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`if constexpr` is only for templates. From [stmt.if]:

> If the `if` statement is of the form `if constexpr`, the value of the condition shall be a contextually converted constant expression of type `bool` (5.20); this form is called a *constexpr if* statement. If the value of
>   the converted condition is `false`, the first substatement is a *discarded statement*, otherwise the second substatement, if present, is a discarded statement. **During the instantation of an enclosing templated entity
>   (Clause 14)**, if the condition is not value-dependent after its instantiation, the discarded substatement (if any) is not instantiated.

Within `X`, the constexpr if statement will prevent the otherwise ill-formed statement from being instantiated. That is the goal of this language feature. But outside of templates, there's no such equivalent gain.

Comment: Which is a pitty and I stumbled just at the same place. You can always put a template parameter for a config condition and add an indirection and implement things there, but I do not understand the severe restriction. It is because of implementation difficulties?